# How to read value of TcxLookupComboBox when looping cxGrid?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl, tcxgrid

I have `cxGrid` that has a column with `TcxLookupComboBox` type linked with `DataSource`

I need to read the value of the `TcxLookupComboBox` fields of each row in the `cxGrid`

I want a code of loop when I can read the data of `TcxLookupComboBox` if spedific column in `cxGrid`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the grid's records and get the values assumed by a column using the [`DataController`](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/cxData.TcxDataController._members)'s [`Values`](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/cxCustomData.TcxCustomDataController.Values) or [`DisplayTexts`](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/cxCustomData.TcxCustomDataController.DisplayTexts) properties as follows:

```
var
  i : Integer;
  View : TcxGridDBTableView;
  Col : TcxGridColumn;
begin
  View := <the gridview, for example cxGridDBTableView1>;
  Col := <the column you want to get the value>;

  i := 0;
  while(i < View.DataController.RecordCount) do
  begin
    ShowMessage(
       'Record index = ' + IntToStr(i) + sLineBreak + 
       'Value = ' + VarToStr(View.DataController.Values[i, Col.Index]) + sLineBreak + 
       'DisplayValue = ' + VarToStr(View.DataController.DisplayTexts[i, Col.Index])
    );
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The problem is that the TcxGridColumn contains TcxLookupComboBox, ans this TcxLookupComboBox contains several columns (ID, Name ...) and I want to read one of the columns of the TcxLookupComboBox only, so I want something that can help me to treat the cell as TcxLookupComboBox